# Problema com metodos

Tags: java

Estou fazendo um programa que calcule IMC, usando metodos sem return.
Programa em questão:

```
package pct;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex02Metodos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
        String sexo;
        double altura, peso, valorIMC = 0;


        System.out.println("Digite sua altura:");
        altura = teclado.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Digite seu peso");
        peso = teclado.nextDouble();
        teclado.nextLine();
        System.out.println("\n\nDigite seu sexo:");
        sexo = teclado.nextLine();

        calcularimc(altura,peso,valorIMC,sexo);


    }
    public static void calcularimc(double altura, double peso, double valorIMC, String sexo){
        valorIMC = peso / (altura * altura);

        if(sexo == "mulher"){
            if(valorIMC < 19.1){
                System.out.println("Abaixo do peso");
            }
            else if(valorIMC == 19.1 & valorIMC <= 25.8 ){
                System.out.println("Peso normal");
            }
            else if(valorIMC == 25.8 & valorIMC <= 27.3){
                System.out.println("Marginalmente acima do peso");
            }
            else if(valorIMC == 27.3 & valorIMC <= 31.1){
                System.out.println("Acima do peso ideal");
            }
            else if(valorIMC > 31.1){
                System.out.println("Obeso");
            }
        }
        else if(sexo =="homem"){
            if(valorIMC < 20.7){
                System.out.println("Abaixo do peso");
            }
            else if(valorIMC == 20.7 & valorIMC <=26.4){
                System.out.println("Peso normal");
            }
            else if(valorIMC == 26.4 & valorIMC <= 27.8){
                System.out.println("Marginalmente acima do peso");
            }
            else if(valorIMC == 27.8 & valorIMC <= 32.3){
                System.out.println("Acima do peso ideal");
            }
            else if(valorIMC > 32.3){
                System.out.println("Obeso");
            }
        }
        }

    }
```

Na hora de executar, não está rodando o metodo, ele encerra.

Comment: Você tentou retirar o `public static void main()` de dentro do escopo da classe e rodar de novo?

Comment: Como você sabe que ele não está executando o método `calcularimc`?

Comment: Desculpe a minha falta de conhecimento sobre o assunto, mas como eu sei? por que não imprimiu nada na tela depois da pergunta de entrada ainda no método principal. O programa se encerrou assim que pediu o entrada sobre o sexo do usuário.

Comment: O método está sendo executado sim, só não está passando pelos _if else_. Só não sei o por que ainda.

Comment: Ta funcionando normalmente.

Comment: É, parece que os if else não estão funcionando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talvez a razão seja utilizar o operador `==` para comparar strings. Elas são objetos, e devem ser comparadas com `equals`. Comparando com o operador `==` você está comparando a referencia do objeto(endereço de memória) e não seu conteúdo em si, como ocorre utilizando o `equals` da classe `String`, e por mais que as strings tenham o mesmo conteúdo, elas ocupam diferentes espaços de memória([salvo exceções](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1643079/5524514)).

Há outros problemas de lógica também, ao invés de utilizar `>=` você estava utilizando `==` na lógica de alguns ifs. Com a alteração abaixo, volta a funcionar normalmente em todas as condições:

```
public static void calcularimc(double altura, double peso, double valorIMC, String sexo) {
    valorIMC = peso / (altura * altura);

    if (sexo.equals("mulher")) {
        if (valorIMC < 19.1) {
            System.out.println("Abaixo do peso");
        } else if (valorIMC >= 19.1 & valorIMC <= 25.8) {
            System.out.println("Peso normal");
        } else if (valorIMC >= 25.8 & valorIMC <= 27.3) {
            System.out.println("Marginalmente acima do peso");
        } else if (valorIMC >= 27.3 & valorIMC <= 31.1) {
            System.out.println("Acima do peso ideal");
        } else if (valorIMC > 31.1) {
            System.out.println("Obeso");
        }
    } else if (sexo.equals("homem")) {
        if (valorIMC < 20.7) {
            System.out.println("Abaixo do peso");
        } else if (valorIMC >= 20.7 & valorIMC <= 26.4) {
            System.out.println("Peso normal");
        } else if (valorIMC >= 26.4 & valorIMC <= 27.8) {
            System.out.println("Marginalmente acima do peso");
        } else if (valorIMC >= 27.8 & valorIMC <= 32.3) {
            System.out.println("Acima do peso ideal");
        } else if (valorIMC > 32.3) {
            System.out.println("Obeso");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Fiz isso, e mesmo assim, parece que os if else não existem. Não imprime na tela as minha condições. O programa se encerre assim que ele pergunta o sexo do usuário.

Comment: @zHardy veja a edição